# Transform density values from a sperical coordinate system to cartesian / script check

Tags: python, numpy, coordinate-systems, astronomy

I have the following problem:

- spherical coordinate system, datacube 50*31*89 full of coordinates
  with density and temperature values
- I need to transport density value from each spherical "cell" into a relevant "cell" in the cartesian system with dimension 150*150*50

I wrote a script, but not sure, if it is orrect.
Would be glad, if someone could check it.

Output that I need is an ascii file with density values. Later I will convert these values to a binary voxel data file to use it in Blender.

```
import numpy as np

# some "fix wired" information from input file
nI = 50
nJ = 31
nK = 89
n = nI * nJ * nK
radius = 3e10 

# define grid data arrays
r = np.zeros( nI )                 # radius
theta = np.zeros( nJ )             # polar angle
phi = np.zeros( nK  )              # azimuth angle
D = np.zeros( ( nI, nJ, nK ) )     # density
T = np.zeros( ( nI, nJ, nK ) )     # temperature 

# read data from input file
file = open( "PLANET3DP.DATA", "r" )
text = file.readlines()
file.close()
i = 0
for line in text:
    if( line.find( "Grid: radial" ) > -1 ):
        I1 = i + 2
    if( line.find( "Grid: polar" ) > -1 ):
        J1 = i + 2
    if( line.find( "Grid: azimuthal" ) > -1 ):
        K1 = i + 2
    if ( line.find( "Data:" ) > -1 ):
        data1 = i + 1
    i = i + 1
for I in range( 0, nI ):
    w = text[ I1 + I ].split()
    r[ I ] = float( w[ 1 ] )
#print( r )
for J in range( 0, nJ ):
    w = text[ J1 + J ].split()
    theta[ J ] = float( w[ 1 ] )
#print( theta )
for K in range( 0, nK ):
    w = text[ K1 + K ].split()
    phi[ K ] = float( w[ 1 ] )
#print( phi )
for i in range( 0, n ):
    w = text[ data1 + i ].split()
    I = int( w[ 0 ] ) - 1
    J = int( w[ 1 ] ) - 1
    K = int( w[ 2 ] ) - 1
    D[ I, J, K ] = float( w[ 3 ] )
    T[ I, J, K ] = float( w[ 4 ] )

# define 3 vectors that describe a 3D cartesian coordinate system
x = np.linspace(-radius,radius,150)
y = np.linspace(-radius,radius,150)
z = np.linspace(-radius,radius,50)

# pick densities from spherical coordiates
D2 = np.zeros( ( 150, 150, 50 ) )
for i in range( 0, 150 ):
    for j in range( 0, 150 ):
        for k in range( 0, 50 ):
            r2 = np.sqrt( x[ i ] ** 2 + y[ j ] ** 2 + z[ k ] ** 2 )
            theta2 = np.arccos( z[ k ] / r2 )
            phi2 = np.arctan2( y[ j ], x[ i ] )
            ii = np.where( r > r2 )
            jj = np.where( theta > theta2 )
            kk = np.where( phi > phi2 )
            if ii[ 0 ].size > 0 and jj[ 0 ].size > 0 and kk[ 0 ].size > 0:
                I = np.min( ii )
                J = np.min( jj )
                K = np.min( kk )
                D2[ i, j, k ] = D[ I, J, K ]
            else:
                D2[ i, j, k ] = 0
#print( D2 )
file = open( "only_density.csv", "w" )
for I in range( 0, 150 ):
    for J in range( 0, 150 ):
        for K in range( 0, 50 ):
            file.write( str( D2[ I, J, K ] ) + "\n" )
file.close()
```

Comment: You may want to tag this `python` and `numpy`, since your actual problem has little to do with astronomy, but is purely a mathematical one.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a data file from one format to a different format?  It would help if you provide a sample input and output or a detailed description of the formats.

Comment: I see. I'm trying to transport data (density) from shperical coordinate system with dimensions 50*31*89 to cartesian system with dimensions 150*150*50. But I'm trying to do this backward. So i take a coordinate in my new cartesian system and try to recalculate it spherical.

Comment: My data looks like this (1st cooridnate):
I = radial position
J = polar position
K = azimuthal position 
**Grid: radial Coordinates** (centers, interfaces)

I, R[cm]
**1**   0.608390297661E+15   0.598400009503E+15

**Grid: polar Coordinates** (centers, interfaces)
J, THETA[0-pi]
**1**   0.207750481931E+01   0.209439510239E+01
  
**Grid: azimuthal Coordinates** (centers, interfaces)
K, PHI[0-2pi]
**1**   0.105896381582E+00   0.705975877211E-01

**Data** : I,J,K,RH: 
1      1      1   0.143367528860E-19

Comment: If it will be helpfull, I can post a link to a my data set and some pictures I have plotted with Matplotlib.

Comment: There are 2 separate problems here: 1) parsing the file and 2) converting between coordinate systems. If you like to get help with parsing you need to post (an excerpt from) your file. As for the conversion, do you need/want to implement something yourself or is it okay to use e.g. something from [scipy.interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)?

Comment: @morningsun Thank you for having interest for my problem. I could send you my data or post them somewhere. If you could find another solution, it would be great! Just tell me, how I can contact you.